# APACHE AUTH PROXY FOR QUESTDB

Tags: apache, authentication, proxy, questdb

I want to configure an apache Auth proxy for access to QuestDB that does not have Authentication system.  I try it to VM in a first time.

I made a very simple configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            AuthType Basic
            Authname "Password Required"
            AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
            Require valid-user
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/

    ProxyRequests Off
</VirtualHost>
```

I configured my QuestDB with a bind adress http://127.0.0.1:9000.

When I go to http://myipadress and give my Apache authentified user, I have :

- **Bad request**
- *refresh*
- **Content without CSS**
- *refresh*
- **Bad request**
- *refresh*
- **QuestDB opened**
- *refresh*

and looping like this forever.

Any idea ?
When I just set the ProxyPass / ProxyPassReverses lines, I got the same phenomenom.
I have enabled my Apache server mods : proxy_http, proxy, rewrite and cache and the default ones that are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The below config is working for me. I think the difference is I am not using a DocumentRoot.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            AuthType Basic
            Authname "Password Required"
            AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
            Require valid-user
    </Proxy>
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName 127.0.0.1:80
  ServerAlias localhost
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```